# Im following the Spring MySql data access walkthrough and I keep getting "Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata."

Tags: java, spring, database, maven

During the walkthrough I have added the specified model, controller and repo. I have added all the required dependencies through spring boot (I beleive) as well as creating the DB through the MySql shell.

The db is the same as the example as well as the basic root user until I can get this to work then will add another user.

Any help would be appreciated as I have had this same issue every single time I have tried to set up a db.

---

My model

```
package com.avorion.dndwiki.Model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity; import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue; import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType; import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) private Integer id;

private String name;

private String email;

public Integer getId() { return id;
    }

public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id;
    }

public String getName() { return name;
    }

public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;
    }

public String getEmail() { return email;
    }

public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email;
    } }
```

My Controller

```
package com.avorion.dndwiki.Controller;

import com.avorion.dndwiki.Model.User; import com.avorion.dndwiki.Repository.UserRepository; import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping; import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping; import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam; import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller // This means that this class is a Controller @RequestMapping(path="/demo") // This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path) public class MainController {
    @Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to handle the data private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY POST Requests public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
            , @RequestParam String email) {
        // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
        // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

User n = new User(); n.setName(name); n.setEmail(email); userRepository.save(n); return "Saved";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/all") public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() { This returns a JSON or XML with the users return userRepository.findAll();
    } }
```

My Repo

```
package com.avorion.dndwiki.Repository;

import com.avorion.dndwiki.Model.User; import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;



//This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

My application properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=root@localhost
spring.datasource.password=thisIsntMyActualPassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

My Pom(Theres a lot here,im just practicing)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Avorion</groupId>
    <artifactId>DnDWiki</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DnDWiki</name>
    <description>DnDWiki</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have tried to set up a number of db with diffrent users and naming conventions. I have reset MySql as well as asking other software engineers.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your password and username is correct. I'm not sure you need to use @localhost in your username